# Add date to to Crystal Report Text Object

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Text Object on my report which is contains some text. What I'd like to do is add a date to the text object that will alaways show the current date. I've tried using a date field, but it is near impossible to line it up correctly.

Any ideas on how to do this? I've been told that there is a way to do this using something like &[], but I can't figure out how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the date inline, double click on the text field then select the date text, you can now click on the formatting button on the toolbar and setup the date format.

Answer (score 1):

You can drag any field, including special ones (Print Date for example) into text object - it will line up without problems.

Comment: That does work, however, I'm unable to format the date once it's added to the text box and if I edit the date before I add it, it won't line up as it should. Any ideas?

Comment: You can edit the textObject by selecting it then pressing `F2`.  Next, select the embedded field, right click it, and choose Format {field name here}...